# Having trouble with RavenDB Multi Map reduce

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb

I'm new to Raven so I'm not even sure if I'm taking the right approach here. I need to generate a list of items whose properties are pulled from separate documents...essentially a JOIN.

Say I have these objects:

```
public class Merchant
{
   public string Id {get;set;}
   public string MerchantName {get;set;}
}

public class Location
{
   public string Id {get;set;}
   public string MerchantId {get;set;}
   public string City {get;set;}
}

public class Item
{
   public string Id {get;set;}
   public string MerchantId {get;set;}
   public string ItemName {get;set;}
}
```

And I need to MapReduce(I think) into a List of MerchantItem

```
public class MerchantItem
{
   public string ItemId {get;set;}
   public string MerchantId {get;set;{
   public string LocationId {get;set;}
   public string ItemName {get;set;}
   public string City {get;set;}
   public string MerchantName {get;set;}
}
```

Here is my (non-working) multi map reduce:

```
AddMap<Merchant>(merchants => from m in merchants
                              select new
                              {
                               ItemId = (string)null,
                               MerchantId = m.Id,
                               LocationId = (string)null,
                               ItemName = (string)null,
                               City = (string)null,
                               MerchantName = m.Name
                              });

AddMap<Location>(locations => from l in locations
                              select new
                              {
                               ItemId = (string)null,
                               MerchantId = l.MerchantId,
                               LocationId = l.Id,
                               ItemName = (string)null,
                               City = l.City,
                               MerchantName = (string)null
                              });

AddMap<Item>(items=> from i in items
                              select new
                              {
                               ItemId = i.Id,
                               MerchantId = i.MerchantId,
                               LocationId = (string)null,
                               ItemName = i.ItemName,
                               City = (string)null,
                               MerchantName = (string)null
                              });

Reduce = results => from r in results
                    group result by r.LocationId
                    into g
                    select new
                    {
                     ItemId = g.Select(x => x.ItemId),
                     MerchantId = g.Select(x => x.MerchantId),
                     LocationId =  g.Key,
                     ItemName = g.Select(x => x.ItemName ).Where(x => x != null).FirstOrDefault(),
                     City =  g.Select(x => x.City ).Where(x => x != null).FirstOrDefault(),
                     MerchantName = g.Select(x => x.MerchantName ).Where(x => x != null).FirstOrDefault()
                     });
```

The idea is that I need a MerchantItem for every Item and Location in the database.  In SQL we're just talking about a couple of joins, but I am totally stumped on how to do this in Raven.

Comment: Perhaps use Raven's Include() functionality as a different (better?) approach? I provided an example when answering this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500043/query-list-of-sub-documents-with-ravendb

Comment: Ha, that was also my question and yes a similar one.  I only just now saw that you had answered it.  I will give your approach a shot. Thanks.

Comment: LOL. I just noticed that as well. What I describe in that answer is what Ayende says below: Include().

Answer (score 0):

Ryan,

You can easily enough get the items and the associated merchant (using `Include`). But your index makes no sense.

What is it that you are trying to DO?

Comment: The only way I know how to explain it is via relational terms, so let's try that.  Merchant has 1-n Locations and 1-n Items.  In a relational db, I would simply join all 3 tables together based on MerchantId and pick out the fields I would need from each row to build my MerchantItem objects.  But ultimately I need to flatten out the three objects to build a 4th object with properties taken from the 3 existing.